# Clarification regarding heat kernel for Brownian motion on a manifold

Tags: probability, probability-theory, partial-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Let $X$ be Brownian motion on a Riemannian manifold $M$ starting at $x\in M$, D a domain and $f$ a bounded continuous function on $D$. Define $\tau_D$ to be the first exit time of $X$ from $D$. $u_f\left(t,x,y\right)=\int_Dp_D\left(t,x,y\right)f\left(y\right)dy$ solves

$
\begin{cases} 
L_Mu_f\left(t,x\right)=0, & t>0,x\in\overline{D}, \\
u_f\left(t,x\right)=0, & t>0,x\in\partial D, \\
\lim_{t\downarrow0}u_f\left(t,x\right)=f\left(x\right), & x\in D.
\end{cases}
$

I have seen the following two formulae written:

$$\mathbb{P}_x\left(X_t\in C, t<\tau_D\right)=\int_Cp_D\left(t,x,y\right)dy$$
and
$$E_x\left(f\left(X_t\right),t<\tau_D\right)=\int_Dp_D\left(t,x,y\right)f\left(y\right)dy.$$

Is $\mathbb{P}_x$ the joint probability of the events $\{X_t\in C\}$ and $\{t<\tau_D\}$? I also do not know what the interpretation for $E_x\left(f\left(X_t\right),t<\tau_D\right)$ is. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, it turns out that $\mathbb{P}_x$ is as I thought and $\mathbb{E}_x\left(f\left(X_t\right),t<\tau_D\right)=\mathbb{E}_x\left(f\left(X_t\right)I_{\{t<\tau_D\}}\right)$.